# How do I reuse my hasher in another hasher?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I have been given a task to write a C++ program that stores an `unordered_set` of objects `street`. At the same time, object `street` is to contain some general info and an `unordered_set` of objects `house`. I have written a structure-hasher for `house`

```
struct house_hasher {
    std::hash<std::string> number_hash;
    std::hash<size_t> storeys_hash;
    std::hash<size_t> aparts_hash;
    std::hash<size_t> residents_hash;
    std::hash<std::string> street_name_hash;
    std::hash<double> pfsm_hash;
    std::hash<double*> pea_hash;
    std::hash<double*> sea_hash;
    std::hash<bool*> ps_hash;
    size_t operator()(const house& h) const {
        const size_t coef = 2'946'901;
        size_t hash_value = 0;
        hash_value = (pow(coef, 8) * number_hash(h.getter_number()) +
            pow(coef, 7) * storeys_hash(h.getter_storeys_n()) +
            pow(coef, 6) * aparts_hash(h.getter_aparts_n()) +
            pow(coef, 5) * residents_hash(h.getter_residents_n()) +
            pow(coef, 4) * street_name_hash(h.getter_street_name()) +
            pow(coef, 3) * pfsm_hash(h.getter_price_for_square_meter()) +
            pow(coef, 2) * pea_hash(h.getter_payments_each_apartments()) +
            coef * sea_hash(h.getter_square_each_apartments()) +
            ps_hash(h.getter_payments_statuses()));
        return hash_value;
    }
};
```

to enable adding `house` to the container and it works correctly. But the thing is that I have to write a structure-hasher for object `street` since it must be addable as well. I assume I could easily add another structure and copy-paste the code from the initial structure to the one mentioned, so that the part, that hashes `houses`, repeats twice in the project but still it seems to be stupid.
What I want to do is to create one more structure-hasher for `streets` but to use the object of `house_hasher` in it and be able to hash houses like that

```
struct street_hasher {
    std::hash<std::string> name_hash;
    std::hash<size_t> number_hash;
    std::hash<size_t> houses_hash;
    std::hash<std::unordered_set<house, house_hasher>> uset_houses_hash;
    size_t operator()(const street& s) const {
        const size_t coef = 2'946'901;
        size_t hash_value = 0;
        size_t add_hash = 0;
        house_hasher hasher_for_house;
        std::unordered_set<house, house_hasher>::iterator uset_it = s.getter_street_uset_houses().begin();
        for (uset_it; uset_it != s.getter_street_uset_houses().end(); ++uset_it) {
            add_hash += hasher_for_house(*uset_it);
        }
        hash_value = (pow(coef, 3) * name_hash(s.getter_street_name()) +
            pow(coef, 2) * number_hash(s.getter_street_number()) +
            coef * houses_hash(s.getter_street_houses_n()) +
            add_hash);
        return hash_value;
    }
};
```

However, this does not seem to be correct. VS throws an error **C2280** `"std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>::_Uhash_compare(const std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq> &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию`

The last few words say an attempt to refer to deleted function occurred.

I have tried a lot of ideas of mine and those found on the net. Still, there is no output. Could anybody please tell me how to solve this tricky problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried placing all the house attributes into a struct, then create a hash of the struct?  This is similar to creating an array of struct rather than parallel arrays of each member.

Comment: Oh, I have just understood that is much easier. I guess reading the task messed with my head as it suggested doing it the way shown. Thanks)

Comment: `std::hash<std::unordered_set<house, house_hasher>> uset_houses_hash;` doesn't look right to me. I don't think there is a standard hash for an `unordered_set`. And since you are not using it anyway (instead you sum up the hashes of individual houses), you could just remove that member.

Comment: Yep, ```std::hash<std::unordered_set<house, house_hasher>> uset_houses_hash``` is of no use here. Already deleted. The error went away, but another problem emerged. It says ```list iterators incompatible``` at the line I initialize the loop in ```street_hasher```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to arrange the street_hasher structure this way (it works but I am sure there is another way to make this work which would be more elegant and laconic):

```
struct street_hasher {
    std::hash<std::string> name_hash;
    std::hash<size_t> number_hash;
    std::hash<size_t> houses_hash;
    size_t operator()(const street& s) const {
        const size_t coef = 2'946'901;
        size_t hash_value = 0;
        size_t add_hash = 0;
        house_hasher hasher_for_house; // need this to hash houses
        std::unordered_set < house, house_hasher > uset = s.getter_street_uset_houses();
        std::unordered_set<house, house_hasher>::iterator uset_it = uset.begin();
        std::unordered_set<house, house_hasher>::iterator end_it = uset.end();
        size_t houses_it = s.getter_street_houses_n() + 2; 
        // there is 2 as we have y = 3 more attributes to hash in street
        // but we start with the power of n - 1, where n = houses_n + y =>
        // => n = s.getter_street_houses_n() + 3
        // => n - 1 = s.getter_street_houses_n() + 2
        hash_value = (pow(coef, houses_it) * name_hash(s.getter_street_name()) +
            pow(coef, houses_it - 1) * number_hash(s.getter_street_number()) +
            pow(coef, houses_it - 2) * houses_hash(s.getter_street_houses_n()) +
            add_hash);
        houses_it -= 3;
        for (uset_it; uset_it != end_it; ++uset_it) {
            add_hash += pow(coef, houses_it) * hasher_for_house(*uset_it);
            --houses_it;
        } 
        // I guess it is much safer to treat each house as an independent attribute
        hash_value += add_hash;
        return hash_value;
    }
};
```

I have deleted `std::hash<std::unordered_set<house, house_hasher>> uset_houses_hash;` from the header and it stopped throwing the error. After one problem went away, another one came. The compiler was angry at how I initialized the loop saying `list iterators incompatible`. I have just rearranged the function a bit by setting so-called static `house_hasher` and iterators. As an addition, I came up with a thought to deal with each house in `unordered_set` as with a different attribute of `street`, so that we avoid collisions (I may have just said something stupid but still let it be this way). Thus, such way of hashing seems to me say more safer. Anyway, it works!

Cheers!